# Is there a linear logic/category that deals with real quantities of resources?

Tags: logic, category-theory, linear-logic

Linear logic models consumption of discrete resources.

Q: Is there an extension of linear logic that models the consumption of numeric resources (e.g., amount of a chemical substance).

Q: If so, does it have a corresponding (non-Cartesian) category? Is this category named/known?

**Alternative intuition**

Linear logic seems to capture properties about objects being consumed, consumed once, consumed at least once, etc. Is there a logic that deals with partial consumption, e.g., where only 1/3 of an object is consumed?

Comment: When you talk of numeric resources, do you refer to resource that are measurable in a continuum space?

Comment: I mean rational/real numbers or fungible resources. For example to prove properties about chemical reactions that describe things like: if I have at least x of substance X and at least y of substance Y I can combine them to get at least 0.3 x + 0.2 y of substance Z?

Comment: [Syntax and Semantics of Quantitative Type Theory](https://bentnib.org/quantitative-type-theory.pdf). Note that the non-negative rational/real numbers are an example of a semiring with the properties they require (technically the reals would only work classically).